# JNA tagged union mapping

Tags: java, jna

How to map following "tagged union" structure to JNA? This structure is used by `libvterm` ([link to source code](https://github.com/neovim/libvterm/blob/89675ffdda615ffc3f29d1c47a933f4f44183364/include/vterm.h#L123)).

```
/**
 * Tagged union storing either an RGB color or an index into a colour palette
 */
typedef union {
  /**
   * Tag indicating which union member is actually valid. This variable
   * coincides with the `type` member of the `rgb` and the `indexed` struct
   * in memory. */
  uint8_t type;

  struct {
    uint8_t type;
    uint8_t red, green, blue;
  } rgb;

  struct {
    uint8_t type;
    uint8_t idx;
  } indexed;
} VTermColor;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although there are many mappings that will work (any 32-bit structure with the right methods used to fetch the values), the canonical way to map this directly is by using JNA's [Union](https://java-native-access.github.io/jna/4.2.1/com/sun/jna/Union.html) class.  The Union will have three elements; either a `byte`, or a structure `RGB` that you can define (an inner class of the Union is fine), or a structure `Indexed` that you will define (again, an inner class).

The `Union` will allocate enough memory on the native side for the largest element (32-bits), and given the structure options you're guaranteed that the first 8 bits of the resulting 32-bit C-side memory will contain the `type` field; based on that value you'll know what is contained in the remaining 24 bits.

If you look at the [source code of JNA's Variant class](https://github.com/java-native-access/jna/blob/aa9341d622acd0c7af04df5cde58b759b5c48be8/contrib/platform/src/com/sun/jna/platform/win32/Variant.java#L628) which maps the [tagged union VARIANT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/oaidl/ns-oaidl-tagvariant), you'll see this implemented on a slightly more complex scale.  The `_VARIANT` class contains these five elements, similar to the 3 elements in your union:

```
        public VARTYPE vt;
        public short wReserved1;
        public short wReserved2;
        public short wReserved3;
        public __VARIANT __variant;
```

For a Union, only one value of `__variant` will be valid.  In this case, the type is set here:

```
   public void setVarType(short vt) {
        this._variant.vt = new VARTYPE(vt);
   }
```

More generally, you can look at the outer `VARIANT` class which uses the Union class `setType()` method to determine whether there's even a valid value: it sets a string corresponding to the active field (in this case `"_variant"`) which is set in the constructor. (You can also set using a class instead of a String.)

In your case, you will want to initialize based on the type value, so you'll start out with the `type` as the default, read its value, and then switch.

You could define your union like this:

```
public class VTermColor extends Union {
    public class RGB extends Structure {
        public byte type;
        public byte red;
        public byte green;
        public byte blue;
    }

    public class Indexed extends Structure {
        public byte type;
        public byte idx;
    }

    public byte type;
    public RGB rgb;
    public Indexed indexed;

    public VTermColor() {
        // initialize knowing only the type, read its value
        this.setType("type");
        this.read();

        // switch union based on type, re-read
        if ((this.type & VTERM_COLOR_TYPE_MASK) == VTERM_COLOR_RGB) {
            this.setType("rgb");
        } else {
            this.setType("indexed");
        }
        this.read();
    }

    public VTermColor(Pointer p) {
        super(p);
        // same remaining code as above
    }
}
```

You probably want to create a few other getter methods to do checking of the `type` value before returning the appropriate fields.

As mentioned at the start, any 32-bit data structure would work.  A somewhat hacky alternative (sacrificing readability and type safety for a lot less code) could simply always use the 4-byte `RGB` structure as defined above. A getter for `type` would always work, while the getters for `red`, `green`, and `blue` would work if valid, otherwise you could create a getter for `idx` that just reads the value of `red`.